# Why does my C++ program print an extra newline?

Tags: c++

ok i have been at this for hours....

```
//after a character is entered, library routines are used to uppercase the
letters. loops the program until "1" is entered

char letter;

while (letter != '1')
{
    cout << "Enter a letter: ";
    cin.get(letter);
    cout << char(toupper(letter)) << '\n';
}
```

everything works but it couts "Enter a letter: " twice...

here is a sample output

```
Enter a letter: h
H
Enter a letter: 

Enter a letter: k
K
Enter a letter: 

Enter a letter: a
A
```

i want it to look like this

```
Enter a letter: h
H
Enter a letter: k
K
Enter a letter: a
A
```

Can you help and explain why it is doing this....

Comment: first try using << endl instead of << '\n' that will eliminate any buffering issues

Comment: also why cin.get and not cin >> ?

Comment: The first letter is you typing, the 2nd is your program printing out.  Isn't it???  You'll probably need to use a package like [ncurses](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/linux-programming/80662-ncurses-cplusplus-tutorial-documentation.html) if you want to make input "invisible".

Comment: no I believe what is happening is that you are sending H and \n, and it prints \n the second time

Comment: You're correct.  I've updated the post title to make it more meaningful.

Comment: @AK4749: No. (std::cin/std::cout) are already synced. When asking for input the output is guranteed to have been flushed.

Comment: @LokiAstari but when asking for output, the input is not guaranteed to have been flushed, correct? - because that is certainly what is going on here. he couts, but leaves a \n in the input

Comment: @AK4749: Wrong. Yes it is (available). What is happening here is that he (OP) is not reading the '\n' from the input (see answers below). But back to you comment. Using std::endl is a red herring. There are **No** buffering issues here. Because (see last comment).

Comment: @LokiAstari right, of course, that I understand from your previous comment. But I'm still confused how cout/cin can be buffer-synced if this situation can happen. Maybe I'm just not understanding you properly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you enter your data, you type the letter then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.  This adds your letter as well as the return character (`\n`) to the stream.  Since `cin.get()` isn't going to wait for your input when there are still characters to extract from the stream, it's picking up the `\n` every other pass.

You can quickly fix this by adding `cin.ignore`:

```
while (letter != '1')
{
    cout << "Enter a letter: ";
    cin.get(letter);
    cin.ignore(256, '\n');
    cout << char(toupper(letter)) << '\n';
}
```

An alterative would be to use the `>>` operator as `cin.get` only retrieves one char at a time:

```
while (letter != '1')
{
    cout << "Enter a letter: ";
    cin >> letter;
    cout << char(toupper(letter)) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Well, using the extraction operator `cin >>` has the same effect.

Comment: The proposed solution is still incorrect.  Anything that uses the results of `cin.get( letter )` without first checking whether it succeeded is incorrect.

Comment: :D yay thanks! just a follow up question...what does the 256 stand for?

Comment: The 256 is the `streamsize` argument.  `cin.ignore` Extracts characters from the input sequence and discards them. The extraction ends when `streamsize` characters have been extracted and discarded or when the character `delim` is found, whichever comes first.

Answer (score 3):

Just change the `cin.get(letter)` to `cin >> letter;`, and it will work as expected.

**EDIT:** Thought I give some more information on this. get() extracts exactly one character from the stream, which will leave the newline character in there as others have pointed out. The next call to get() will extract it and terminate immediately instead of waiting for input, since the stream still had data. The `>>`-operator on the other hand, is made exactly for what you're trying to do here: Read a value from stdin until the return key is pressed. So it consumes the newline as well, causing the next call to `operator<<()` to block until new data is entered by the user.

**Note:** One more thing to keep in mind: `>>`-extracting into a char will extract at most one character from the stream, but it does not prevent the user from entering more characters before pressing enter. This will produce some output like the following:

```
niko@lethal-guitar:~$ ./a.out 
Enter a letter: a
A
Enter a letter: asas
A
Enter a letter: S
Enter a letter: A
Enter a letter: S
```

This is because the operator removes one char and the newline, but keeps the remaining chars in the stream. These will terminate the next three `operator>>()`-calls immediately.

Comment: Whether you use `cin.get( letter )` or `cin >> letter` is irrelevant to the question.  The problem is 1) he uses the results without testing whether the input actually succeeded, and 2) he doesn't take any steps to turn off the usual line processing of the OS.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, because you don't check whether `cin.get` succeeds
or not.  You will almost certainly output the last character you
read twice.  Your loop should be:

```
while ( letter != '1' && cin.get( letter ) ) ...
```

or

```
while ( cin.get( letter ) && letter != '1' ) ...
```

Note too that on most systems, `cin.get()` will not return until
you hit enter (supposing input from the keyboard).  So you'll
output `"Enter a letter: "`, and then wait until the enter key
is pressed.  You'll then loop without waiting, reading all of
the characters you've entered, until you've read `'\n'`.  There
are no provisions for character-wise input in the C++ standard,
and the techiques for doing it vary radically from one system
to the next.